# Vue + axios not update DOM when value change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have loop for uploading file

```
      this.fileUpload.filter((file) => !file.error)
        .map((file, index_file) => {
          var formData = new FormData();
          formData.append("folderID", id);
          formData.append("folderName", name);
          formData.append("type", type);
          formData.append(`content`, file);

          fileService
            .uploadfiles(
              formData,
              (event) => {
                file.status = "uploading";
                file.uploadPercentage =
                  Math.round((event.loaded * 100) / event.total) * 0.9;
                if (file.uploadPercentage == 90) {
                  file.status = "uploaded";
                }
                console.log(  file.uploadPercentage);
              }
            )
            .then((result) => {
              file.uploadPercentage = 100;
              file.status = "done";
            })
            .catch(() => {
              file.status = "uploaded";
            });
        });
```

p.s. fileService.uploadfiles file for create fuction to call axios.post

and div for show uploading

```
   <div v-for="(file, file_index) in fileUpload" :key="`file_preview_${file_index}_${file.name}_${file.status}`">

{{ file.uploadPercentage }}
</div>
```

I don't understand why percentage on div not upload but in console it log percen of write file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46126.png)

Comment: "but in console it log percen of write file" where in the console? We don't see any `console.log` in here

Comment: I updated console.log and image for log

Comment: because **this.fileUpload** is not reactive as you expect

Comment: Try using index, like: this.fileUpload[file_index].uploadPercentage = yourValue

Comment: @Radeanu Can explain more about first comment.  And I tried to use index not work.

Comment: try appending file.uploadPercentage to the :key also; looks like what you bind doesnt change so doesnt get rerender; or try making a sub component "PercentDisplay" and do a getter on the percent

Comment: @4LPH4BET Vue2 has some limitations in reactivity, I can't explain in two words, read more on Vue docs or search about it. Can you explain how you define **this.fileUpload** and if property **uploadPercentage** exist for each file at start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add $nextTick into arrow function to froce rerender and add v-if rerenderProgress to template.

```
uploadfiles(
              formData,
              (event) => {
                file.status = "uploading";
                file.uploadPercentage = Math.round((event.loaded * 100) / event.total) * 0.9;
                this.rerenderProgress = false;
                this.$nextTick(function () {
                  this.rerenderProgress = true;
                });
                // this.$forceUpdate();
                if (file.uploadPercentage == 90) {
                  file.status = "uploaded";
                }
              },
              { cancelToken }
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Vue.set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) as explained in the link

> Due to limitations in JavaScript, there are types of changes that Vue cannot detect. However, there are ways to circumvent them to preserve reactivity.

```
Vue.set(file, 'status', 'uploading');
Vue.set(file, 'uploadPercentage', Math.round((event.loaded * 100) / event.total) * 0.9);
```

Comment: I tried to used this.$set it doesn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use $forceUpdate() to manualy update virtual dom**

```
 fileService
        .uploadfiles(
          formData,
          (event) => {
            file.status = "uploading";
            file.uploadPercentage =
              Math.round((event.loaded * 100) / event.total) * 0.9;
            if (file.uploadPercentage == 90) {
              file.status = "uploaded";
            }
            console.log(  file.uploadPercentage);
            this.$forceUpdate()
          }
        )
```